# Calling stored procedure with jpa 2.x throws illegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following procedure on my mssql server which I want to execute from my java code

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @newUid bigint

EXECUTE @RC = [TEST_DB].[foobar].[getNextUid] @newUid OUTPUT
```

In my code I have defined an entity and using the NamedStoredProcedureQuery annotation to define it

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name = "foobar.getNextUid",
    procedureName = "foobar.getNextUid",
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = Long.class, name = "newUid")
    }
)
```

When I call this stored procedure in my test it throws an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : foobar.getNextUid
```

I also tried it with naming the parameter in my annotation as @newUid

Here is my Testcase

```
EntityManager entityManager = managerEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("foobar.getNextUid");
query.setParameter("@newUid", 1);
long nextUid = (long) query.getOutputParameterValue("newUid");

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing 
query.getOutputParameterValue("@newUid");
by 
query.getOutputParameterValue("newUid");